# How to set the event name in queue configurations?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs

I have a s3 bucket and a SQS defined in cloudformation, it works perfectly but I have not found a way to configuration the "event name" anywhere from cloudformation and it always use a system-generated id as the name (see picture below), anyone knows a way to do it? thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe [`TopicName`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html#cfn-sns-topic-topicname) in [AWS::SNS::Topic](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-sns-topic.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible through Cloudformation as it isn't mentioned in the documenation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-notificationconfig-queueconfig.html

However, it does look like you can specify the id through the AWS S3 API by specifying the optional Id field in the put bucket notification configuration:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketNotificationConfiguration-property

If you're desperate to the control the id, a custom resource is the only way to go. If you want different notification on the same S3 bucket to be controlled by different cloudformation templates, you'll need to go down the custom resource route anyway.